# python selenium: Error 'TimeoutException' with NO iFRAME

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click a button with python selenium and got 'NoSuchElementException' error message.
The button is for pop-up survey form. When I click it manually, hidden form pops up with NO directing to another url.

My purpose is to click the button and editing value(address, name..etc) automatically in the form.
Or if click is not necessary, I prefer editing it without click.
I'm sorry that I can't attach url and full HTML as it needs personal log-in

- There NO tags named 'iframe' in full HTML (even 'frame' and 'shadow')
- got enough time(time.sleep) for loading
- have changed to Xpath, css selector instead of id

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\potg.py", line 59, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"]'))).click()
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

**Button**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"> surver_form </button>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
# click
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"]'))).click()
```

**HTML summary**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
</head>

<body class="no-skin" data-view="/release/detail" data-js="true">
<div type="hidden" id="wmsBillingUrl" value="https://..net"></div>
<div class="spin" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="script-layout"></div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default"></div>
<div id="main-container" class="main-container"></div>
    <div class="main-content"></div>
        <div id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
            <div class="row"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="releaseVendorInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"> 수정
                        </button></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the page URL?

Comment: Sorry It is comany internal site. Not possible to connect from outside.

Comment: Try driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,”button#btnReleaseInfoModal”).click()

Comment: Also check if it’s in any shadow roots as well.

Comment: not working with error "driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,”button#btnReleaseInfoModal”).click()
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character '”' (U+201D)"

Comment: Replace” with  "